# Get url from previous h2 a element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, url, dom

Using jQuery, while in the span element, without knowing post-383 id and class, how can I retrieve the url within the h2 a element?

The html code:

```
<div id="post-1383" class="post-1383>
<h2 class="entry-title">
<a href="http://example.com/soul-music/">Soul Music</a>
</h2>
<span class="btn"></span> 
</div>
```

Something like this?
`$('.btn').previous('a').attr('href');`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) or [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/), like this:

```
$('.btn').prev('h2').find('a').attr('href');
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/7PEDP/).  The `<a>` isn't a *sibling* so `.prev()` won't won't work, you have to go back to the `<h2>` which *is* a sibling, then go inside it to get the `<a>` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Close. Really close. You could use the jQuery traversal function .prev() to get the previous element. If you pass a string with the type of element you want it will give you your answer. so something like `$('.btn').prev('a')` should do the trick. But yeah you had it!

Comment: In this case `<a>` is a nephew, or niece depending on how you think of anchors I guess...but it's not a *sibling* which is all `.prev()` works on :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments,  $('.tw_btn').prev('a').attr('href') did not work, but almost ;)